# No me es posible crear codigo QR en C#

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo este codigo el cual quiero accesar a la parte de QR, para poder generar uno, pero al momento de crear un registro en RegistroEvento al momento de mandar a llamar AltaQRBoleto(1, Correo); (A pesar de mandarlo a llamar dos veces) no realiza ninguna acción, ¿A qué se debe esto?

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //write your handler implementation here.
;
            string Tipo = context.Request.QueryString["Tipo"];

            switch (Tipo)
            {
                case "registro":
                    {
                        RegistroEvento(context);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static void RegistroEvento(HttpContext context)
        {
            Mensajes claseMensajes = new Mensajes();

            string NombreEmpresa = context.Request.QueryString["NE"];
            string NombreAsistente = context.Request.QueryString["NA"];
            string Puesto = context.Request.QueryString["PU"];
            string Correo = context.Request.QueryString["CO"];
            string Telefono = context.Request.QueryString["TE"];

            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["I_Registros"].ToString()))
            {
                conexion.Open();

                using (SqlCommand orden = new SqlCommand("PROC_RegistroEvento @NombreEmpresa , @NombreAsistente , @Puesto , @Correo , @Telefono , @Evento", conexion))
                {
                    //@NombreEmpresa 
                    orden.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NombreEmpresa", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                    orden.Parameters["@NombreEmpresa"].Value = NombreEmpresa;
                    //@NombreAsistente 
                    orden.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NombreAsistente", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                    orden.Parameters["@NombreAsistente"].Value = NombreAsistente;
                    //@Puesto 
                    orden.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Puesto", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                    orden.Parameters["@Puesto"].Value = Puesto;
                    //@Correo 
                    orden.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Correo", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                    orden.Parameters["@Correo"].Value = Correo;
                    //@Telefono 
                    orden.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Telefono", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                    orden.Parameters["@Telefono"].Value = Telefono;
                    //@Evento 
                    orden.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Evento", SqlDbType.Int));
                    orden.Parameters["@Evento"].Value = 1;

                    int id = 0;
                    string regreso = "";

                    using (SqlDataReader lector = orden.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (lector.Read())
                        {
                            id = (int)lector["id"];
                            regreso = (string)lector["RegresoDatos"];
                        }
                        lector.Close();

                        AltaQRBoleto(1, Correo);

                        claseMensajes.Tipo = "RegistroEvento";
                        claseMensajes.cadenaRegreso = regreso;

                        AltaQRBoleto(1, Correo);
                    }
                }
                conexion.Close();
            }
            context.Response.Write(claseMensajes.toJson());
        }

        public static void AltaQRBoleto(int idEvento, string Correo)
        {
            int idFolioRegistro = 0;
            string UUIDEvento = "";

            string FolioManual = "";

            byte[] CodigoBarras = null;
            byte[] RptBoleto = null;

            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["I_Registros"].ToString()))
            {
                conexion.Open();

                using (SqlCommand orden = new SqlCommand(@"
SELECT [idRegistro], [FolioAsistenciaEvento] FROM [dbo].[EventosRegistros]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Asistentes] ON [Asistentes].[idPersona] = [EventosRegistros].[idPersona]
        WHERE [Correo] = @CORREO AND [idEvento] = @EVENTO", conexion))
                {
                    orden.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CORREO", Correo);
                    orden.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EVENTO", idEvento);

                    SqlDataReader lector = orden.ExecuteReader();
                    while(lector.Read())
                    {
                        idFolioRegistro = (int)lector["idRegistro"];
                        UUIDEvento = (string)lector["FolioAsistenciaEvento"];
                    }
                    lector.Close();

                    Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.QrCode clase = new Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.QrCode();
                    Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.QrEncoder claseee = new Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.QrEncoder(Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);
                    clase = claseee.Encode(UUIDEvento);
                    Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.Windows.Render.GraphicsRenderer lectorRender = new Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.Windows.Render.GraphicsRenderer(new Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.Windows.Render.FixedCodeSize(400, Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.Windows.Render.QuietZoneModules.Zero), Brushes.Black, Brushes.White);
                    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                    lectorRender.WriteToStream(clase.Matrix, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png, ms);
                    CodigoBarras = ReadFully(ms);
                    Random claseRandom = new Random();

                    FolioManual = idFolioRegistro.ToString() + "." + claseRandom.Next(1111, 9999).ToString();

                    orden.CommandText = "UPDATE [dbo].[EventosRegistros] SET [FolioManual] = @FOLIOMANUAL, [QR] = @QR WHERE [idRegistro] = @ID";
                    orden.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FOLIOMANUAL", FolioManual);
                    orden.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QR", CodigoBarras);
                    orden.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", idFolioRegistro);

                    orden.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    DataSet regresoRPT = new DataSet();

                    orden.CommandText = @"
SELECT [Evento], [Ubicacion], [FechaInicio], [FechaFin], 
        [NombreEmpresa], [NombreAsistente], [Puesto], [FolioManual], [QR] 
FROM [dbo].[Eventos]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[EventosRegistros] ON [EventosRegistros].[idEvento] = [Eventos].[idEvento]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Asistentes] ON [Asistentes].[idPersona] = [EventosRegistros].[idPersona]
        WHERE [idRegistro] = @ID
";
                    regresoRPT.Load(orden.ExecuteReader(), LoadOption.PreserveChanges, "RegistroEntrada");
                }
                conexion.Close();
            }
        }

        public static byte[] ReadFully(System.IO.Stream input)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que podria comentar es que definir un `while` de un reader para asignar variables no tine ningun sentido, si vas a tomar un valrod el reader usa el `if`

```
if(lector.Read())
{
   id = (int)lector["id"];
   regreso = (string)lector["RegresoDatos"];
}
```

porque si vas a recorrer deberias asignar un lista o coleccion cuando iteras en el while, asi no pisas el valor anterior

**>>al momento de mandar a llamar AltaQRBoleto(1, Correo); no realiza ninguna acción,**

Puedo ver que la accion de actualizar depende de un id de folio que asignas por parametro al UPDATE

Lo que deberias hacer es poner un breakpoint he inspeccionar que el id que envias en el UPDATE existe como registro, porque sino existeno va  actualizar

Tambien podrias validar cuanro row afecta la ejecucion el UPDATE

```
int rowafectadas = orden.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

si el valor de `rowafectadas` es cero entonces quiere decir que el id que le asignas no esta encontrando ningun registro